# /usr/local/bin first in PATH, but executable in /usr/bin found first

Tags: paths, cmake

I'm having a strange problem with an Ubuntu 12.04 server:

```
hithwen@ip:~$ cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.12.2

buildbot@ip:~$ cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.7
```

So, different users are executing different versions, ok, let's see where are they located:

```
hithwen@ip:~$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake

buildbot@ip:~$ which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
```

So it seems I need to fix buildbot user's path but:

```
buildbot@ip:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

`/usr/local/bin` is already before `/usr/bin`, how can I solve this?

I cannot uninstall the `cmake` package because other packages depend on it and I cannot upgrade it via repositories because last version is not available in 12.04 repos.

Answer (score 5):

The explanation was given by the `hash` command:

> hash command maintains a hash table, which has the used command’s path
>   names. When you execute a command, it searches for a command in the
>   variable $PATH. But if the command is available in the hash table, it
>   picks up from there and executes it.
>
> You can delete a particular command from a hash table using -d option

So I did:

```
buildbot@ip:~$ hash
hits    command
   3    /usr/bin/which
   1    /usr/bin/vim
   2    /usr/bin/cmake

buildbot@ip:~$ $ hash -d cmake
buildbot@ip:~$ hash
hits    command
   4    /usr/bin/which
   1    /usr/bin/vim
buildbot@ip:~$ cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.7
buildbot@ip:~$ which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
```

Why is it not finding `/usr/local/bin/cmake`?

```
$ /usr/local/bin/cmake --version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/cmake: Permission denied
```

So this user didn't have permission to access that file.

I reinstalled `cmake` and that fixed it.

Comment: This is a partial answer. So Have you tried `chmod` or `chown` if it works?

Comment: Yes, it didnt work, kept throwing permission denied error. I reinstalled cmake (from sources) and then worked

Comment: Could you add what fixed problem to your answer, So it will be complete. However, I believe that `hash -d cmake` would fix it too, Reference [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)

Comment: hash -d (or -r) fixed the problem of executing one instead of the another. After that I realized that I could not execute the one I wanted, which was a different problem

Comment: Well, what are the permissions of `/usr/local/bin/cmake`, then?

Comment: By the way, the correct answer to the question of why the version in `/usr/bin` is executed despite `/usr/local/bin` being first in `PATH` is that the user does not have permission to execute the one in `/usr/local/bin`; nothing to do with the `hash` command.